# R: creating a data.frame with NULL values

Tags: r, null

I want to have `NULL` values in my data.frame (not `NA`). And the following doesn't seem to work.

```
> data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(NULL, NULL, NULL))
Error in data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(NULL, NULL, NULL)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0
```

My goal is to output my data.frame into a .csv file, and the cells with the `NULL` values should be blank.

Comment: Perhaps `data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = "")`.

Comment: `d <- data.frame(x=1:3); d$y <- replicate(3, NULL)`

Comment: @Masoud But if you save that data frame to a CSV file, it looks blank on column `y`. I think it depends on what Adrian needs.

Comment: Why NULLs? What to you plan on storing in there? Generally you can't have collections of NULL values in R. Use NA values and `write.table()` allows you to control how those values are rendered: `na = "NA"`

Comment: In general, having literal `NULL` values within a data.frame is really problematic. I think the more appropriate question to be asking (and you did) is *"how to get empty values in a CSV"*.

Comment: @r2evans solution seems to give: `dput(d)`
`structure(list(x = 1:3, y = list(NULL, NULL, NULL)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @www thanks, but if I were to read the file back into R, column 'y' is still class `NA`? I'm asking this question because someone said `NA` is not valid for a floating point numeric field in mysql. So I would like to convert them to a null.

Comment: @Adrian I am not familiar with mysql so I may not be able to help, but you may want to be more clear about what you really want. Do you want to import a data frame from R to mysql with `NA` converted to blank? I feel like you may want to have a new post with some clarification of your original question.

Comment: @www yes, I guess that's the idea. But I'm not sure whether a blank necessarily is equivalent to `NULL` in mysql. I'll have to do more digging. Feel free to add your comment as an answer though.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks, but I will keep my comment as a comment. Good luck on finding the way to bridge R and mysql.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the dataframe with `NULL` entries using:

`> data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = I(list(NULL, NULL, NULL))`

---

Explanation:

If you want to use `data.frame` to include columns that are constantly `NULL`, you need to protect them using `I`.

You also have to input a `list` rather than a `c` of `NULL`s. That's because `c(NULL, NULL, NULL)` is identical to `NULL` -- `NULL`s can't be concatenated. Nor can they be elements of a vector, so every column that contains `NULL` values needs to be a list rather than a vector.

Using `write.table` and similar functions will call `as.character` on the column full of `NULL`s, writing the string "NULL" in the null cell. If you don't want that behaviour, it's probably best to use empty strings instead of `NULL`s.